# SQL Select the first Column to match criteria of Many columns in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, multiple-columns

Good Day,

So I'm stuck with a SQL query in which the table I'm querying has multiple sequential columns, such as

```
Property1,
Property2,
Property3,
Property4,
Property5
..etc
```

Now there are about 64 columns descending in the same naming convention. 
They are varchar of type and marked by a single "Y" or "N" stating boolean function.(Not my design)

Now where I'm stuck is that in my query I need to return the First Property column that's marked as "Y" in a single record..

I've searched around but could not have come upon the same question asked elsewhere.. Maybe I'm just missing it?

It would really be appreciated should anyone have a hint for me to follow or so on?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: which RDMS are you using ?

Comment: use dynamic sql with loop?

Comment: put what you have try previously  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
CASE WHEN QryGroup1 = 'Y' then 'QryGroup1'
WHEN QryGroup2 = 'Y' then 'QryGroup2'
WHEN QryGroup3 = 'Y' then 'QryGroup3'
WHEN QryGroup10 = 'Y' then 'QryGroup10'
else ''
end as [SelectedBP]
from OCRD
```

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is to concatenate all fields in one string and then find the index of the first occurrence of `Y` and form a field label as `PROPERTY`+`FIRST OCCURRENCE INDEX`.
If `Y` is not found then `PROPERTY0` appears in this query you can handle this with CASE statement for example.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a395/1)

```
select id,
       'PROPERTY'+
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CHARINDEX('Y',property1+property2+property3)) 

from T
```

Answer (score 2):

that design is horrible. But this should work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Property1 = 'Y' THEN 'Property1'
            WHEN Property2 = 'Y' THEN 'Property2'
            [...]
       ELSE 'None'
       END
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider unpivot

```
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1), Property1 char(1),
Property2 char(1),
Property3 char(1),
Property4 char(1),
Property5 char(1))

insert @t values('N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y')
insert @t values('N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y')
insert @t values('N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y')

;with a as
(
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) position from @t
  unpivot
  (Property FOR colname IN           
  ([Property1], [Property2], [Property3], [Property4], 
   [Property5]/*include more properties here*/) ) AS unpvt  
)
select t.id, coalesce(colname, 'Not found') colname
from @t t
outer apply 
(select top 1 id, colname, position
from a where Property = 'Y'
and t.id = id
order by id
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work as well:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX ( 'Y' , CONCAT(Property1,Property2,...,Property64) )
```

It returns a numeric index of the column and it has the advantage that you can define a function based index to speed up the query.